# How to backdate a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a message on the timeline in the past and I get the following error:
"Facebook.FacebookOAuthException : (OAuthException - #100) (#100) You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a published post"
I tried to put the current date, a past date or a future date; the result is the same.

I think it may be a problem with the way I obtain the unix timestamp.

Here is the code:

```
public void PostPostsOnTestUserTimeline()
    {

        string userId = "[TEST_USER_ID]"; 

        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = "Check out this funny article - 39";

        parameters.scheduled_publish_time = GetUnixTimestamp(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20));

        client.Post(string.Format("{0}/feed", userId), parameters);


    }

    private long GetUnixTimestamp(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        double secondsDouble = (dateTime - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime()).TotalSeconds;
        return Convert.ToInt64(secondsDouble);
    }
```

Any idea why it crashes? 
I am writing on the timeline of a test user created at "created_time": "2013-03-05T12:34:15+0000". If I don't specify the scheduled_publish_time, it works fine.

Thank you,
Iulia

Comment: You said you're doing this on a test user, is that correct? I'm almost sure you can't date the feed posts on a user's timeline

Comment: Hi Igy, thanks for the idea. I tried on my account and on a test user account. Unfortunately, I got the same error in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to backdate feed posts on user timelines - this feature only exists for Pages or for Open Graph publishing

Comment: Thank you, Igy. I think you're right. The docs only tell about backdating posts on pages or on app actions. I saw no parameter in publishing /PROFILE_ID/FEED for setting the post time:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/

Comment: How do you do for pages via api ?